# How to push a value inside a vector which in a c++ pair?

Tags: c++, c++14, priority-queue, std-pair

I have come across a scenario where I am not able to find a way to push a value in the `vector` which is in the `pair`. I have made a `priority_queue` of `pair<int, vector<string>>` and I want to push values in the `vector`, for example:

```
priority_queue<pair<int, vector<string>> pq;
```

I want to know how to push elements in this priority queue.

Comment: what exactly do you want to achieve? modify the contents of the `vector<string>` after the pair containing it has been `push`ed or `emplace`d in `pq`?

Comment: `pq.push({1, {"hello", "world"}});`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have access to the underlying container of a `std::priority_queue`, so you can't access any of the `std::vector` elements you store in it, other than the `top()` element, eg:

```cpp
priority_queue<pair<int, vector<string>> pq;
pq.push(...);
pq.emplace(...);
...
// use pq.top().second as needed...
```

You can iterate the strings in the `vector` in the `pair` returned by `top()`, but you can't `push_back()` more string into the `vector` since the `pair` will be `const`, and thus the `vector` will also be `const`.

`std::priority_queue` is probably not the best container for you to use. Maybe a `std::map` would make more sense?

```cpp
map<int, vector<string>> m;
m[1] = vector<string>{"I", "a"};
m[1].push_back(...);
```

[Live Demo](https://ideone.com/u311JL)

Comment: Please do not recommend code to novice developers with multiple `operator[]` with the same agrument. `std::map::operator[]` is quite expensive operation.

Comment: @Slava then how do you expect to access an element of a given key multiple times?  Are you thinking of something like `auto &elem = m[1]; elem = {"I", "a"}; elem.push_back(...);`?  There is nothing wrong using using `operator[]` like this.  If you want more efficiency, use `std::unordered_map` instead.

Comment: Still missing the point that OP did not clarify, what he needs, and you are suggesting some data structures. Also, add to @Slava said, a suggestion for `using namespace std;` for a newbie-demo also not a good idea.

Comment: Yes, something like that. And I may need `std::map` for a different reason, I do not think that is a good excuse to put unnecessary inefficiency into your code. Especially that using `operator[]` in the first place is not efficient either.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you so much for the clarification. I was able to solve the problem and here is how I approached it.

```
typedef pair<int, vector<string>> pi;
class Compare {
    public:
    bool operator() (pair<int, vector<string>> a, pair<int, vector<string>> b) {
        return a.first > b.first;
    }  
};

class Solution {
public:
    
    string arrangeWords(string text) {
        int n = text.length();
        if(n==0)
            return "";
        text[0] = tolower(text[0]);
        unordered_map<int, vector<string>> m;
        string temp = "";
        for(int i = 0;i<n;i++) {
            if(text[i] != ' ') {
                temp += text[i];
            } else {
                m[temp.length()].push_back(temp);
                temp = "";
            }
            if(i==n-1) {
                m[temp.length()].push_back(temp);
            }
        }
        
        
        priority_queue<pi, vector<pi>, Compare> pq;
        for(auto x: m) {
            pq.push(make_pair(x.first, x.second));
        }
        
        string res = "";
        while(!pq.empty()) {
            auto t = pq.top(); pq.pop();
            int len = t.second.size();
            for(int i=0;i<len;i++) {
                res += t.second[i];
                res += " ";
            }
        }
        res[0] = toupper(res[0]);
        return res.substr(0, res.length()-1);
    }
};
```